# When i installed and link react-native-admob in project application got crash on load time

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I am facing problem in react-native before install react-native-admob my app was working fine but after installed and linked by this library my app getting crash on loading time.

I installed latest version of react-native-admob (react-native-admob@next)

react native version: 0.57.8

react version: 16.6.3

Testing on Android oreo

android/build.gradle code

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
    common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
     ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
  }
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
 }


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '4.4'
distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
 }
```

Please help me.

If you want anythings for clarification i will provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto 
node-module/react-native-admob/android/build.gradle file

replace the line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

with the following line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```